# Set inclusion faster with set literals

Tags: python, performance

In the following I time `10_000_000` checks of whether if `10` is in `{0, ..., 9}`.

In the first check I use an intermediate variable and in the second one I use a literal.

```py
import timeit

x = 10
s = set(range(x))
number = 10 ** 7

stmt = f'my_set = {s} ; {x} in my_set'
print(f'eval "{stmt}"')
print(timeit.timeit(stmt=stmt, number=number))

stmt = f'{x} in {s}'
print(f'eval "{stmt}"')
print(timeit.timeit(stmt=stmt, number=number))
```

Output:

```py
eval "my_set = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} ; 10 in my_set"
1.2576093
eval "10 in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}"
0.20336140000000036
```

How is it that the second one is way faster (by a factor of 5-6 approximately)? Is there some runtime optimisation performed by Python, e.g., if the inclusion check if made on a literal? Or maybe is it due to garbage collection (since it is a literal python garbage collects it right after use)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't testing the same two things -- in the first test, you're timing two assignments and lookups in addition to the membership test:

```py
In [1]: import dis
   ...: x = 10
   ...: s = set(range(x))

In [2]: dis.dis("x in s")
  1        0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
           2 LOAD_NAME                1 (s)
           4 CONTAINS_OP              0
           6 RETURN_VALUE

In [3]: dis.dis("my_set = s; x in my_set")
  1        0 LOAD_NAME                0 (s)
           2 STORE_NAME               1 (my_set)
           4 LOAD_NAME                2 (x)
           6 LOAD_NAME                1 (my_set)
           8 CONTAINS_OP              0
          10 POP_TOP
          12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
          14 RETURN_VALUE

# By request
In [4]: dis.dis("s = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}; 10 in s")
  1        0 BUILD_SET                0
           2 LOAD_CONST               0 (frozenset({0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}))
           4 SET_UPDATE               1
           6 STORE_NAME               0 (s)
           8 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
          10 LOAD_NAME                0 (s)
          12 CONTAINS_OP              0
          14 POP_TOP
          16 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
          18 RETURN_VALUE
```

The *actual* difference between using literals and `x in s` is that the latter needs to go perform a lookup in globals, i.e., the difference is `LOAD_NAME` vs `LOAD_CONST`:

```py
In [5]: dis.dis("10 in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}")
  1        0 LOAD_CONST               0 (10)
           2 LOAD_CONST               1 (frozenset({0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}))
           4 CONTAINS_OP              0
           6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Times:

```py
In [6]: %timeit x in s
28.5 ns ± 0.792 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [7]: %timeit 10 in {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
20.3 ns ± 0.384 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Comment: Also, for the sake of completeness, could you please also add the result of `dis.dis('x = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} ; 10 in x')` (which is the first test I made) to your answer?

Comment: Done, but fwiw, `dis` is a built-in module. You can always try it for yourself!

Comment: Thanks. (I made the test, but I did not know I could edit your answer.)

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: Re: your first comment, which I missed. No, it's due to the fact that it's a literal. Sets are hashed collections, meaning lookups are `O(1)`; size doesn't matter.